# Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor error, when following the example from Keras website

Tags: python, keras

I am following this example https://keras.io/examples/rl/ddpg_pendulum/

and I am getting an error on the line

I am using tensorflow Version: 2.10.0 and Gym 0.26.2

```
tf_prev_state = tf.expand_dims(tf.convert_to_tensor(prev_state), 0)
```

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor.
  File "C:\Users\vlad.nanu\Documents\GitHub\ml-hub\pendulum.py", line 236, in <module>
    tf_prev_state = tf.expand_dims(tf.convert_to_tensor(prev_state), 0)
ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor.
```

Comment: What versions are you using? I tried it in the colab with tf 2.9.2 and gym 0.25.2 and it worked without a problem.

Comment: I am using the following 
pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.10.0
pip show gym
Name: gym
Version: 0.26.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the [release notes](https://github.com/openai/gym/releases/tag/0.26.0) of the latest gym release (0.26.x), you will find 2 breaking changes that affect the pendulum code regarding `env.Step` and `env.Reset`.

You can change the three following lines (see `#changed`):

```py
for ep in range(total_episodes):

    prev_state, _ = env.reset() # changed
    episodic_reward = 0

    while True:
        # Uncomment this to see the Actor in action
        # But not in a python notebook.
        # env.render()

        tf_prev_state = tf.expand_dims(tf.convert_to_tensor(prev_state), 0)

        action = policy(tf_prev_state, ou_noise)
        # Recieve state and reward from environment.
        state, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action) # changed

        buffer.record((prev_state, action, reward, state))
        episodic_reward += reward

        buffer.learn()
        update_target(target_actor.variables, actor_model.variables, tau)
        update_target(target_critic.variables, critic_model.variables, tau)

        # End this episode when `done` is True
        if terminated or truncated: # changed
            break

        prev_state = state

    ep_reward_list.append(episodic_reward)

    # Mean of last 40 episodes
    avg_reward = np.mean(ep_reward_list[-40:])
    print("Episode * {} * Avg Reward is ==> {}".format(ep, avg_reward))
    avg_reward_list.append(avg_reward)
```

Comment: great, works, thanks.